# Python bot.commands not working for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I am making a discord bot for school and I am trying to use this:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)
  print("Test")
```

But this does not work when I try the command in my discord server. This is my full code:

```
#Imports om de code werkend te maken.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#Stukje om de bot aan te zetten en aan de eisen te voldoen van Discord.
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)
  print("Test")

    

#Zet de bot aan.
client.run("TOKEN")
```

I want that the commands work (So I can work from that point on)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have both a `Bot` and a `discord.Client` object. Just use one.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)
  print("Test")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

You were creating both a `Bot` and a `Client` and registering the command with the `Bot` but then running the `Client`.